# Need to convert string/char to ascii values

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, winforms

I need to convert char to hex values. Refer to the Ascii table but I have a few examples listed below:

- char 1 = 31
  2 = 32
  3 = 33
  4 = 34
  5 = 35
  A = 41
  a = 61 etc

Therefore string str = "12345";
Need to get the converted str = "3132333435"

Answer (score 9):

I think this is all you'll need:

```
string finalValue;
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourString);
foreach (Byte b in ascii) 
{
  finalValue += b.ToString("X");
}
```

More info on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx

Edit: To Hex:

```
string finalValue;
int value;
foreach (char c in myString)
{
  value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
  finalValue += value.ToString("X"); 
  // or finalValue = String.Format("{0}{1:X}", finalValue, value);
}
// use finalValue
```

Comment: At first, I didn't understand the hex comment, so I rewrote it.  This morning SO told me the comment was new so I look again, and I just forgot the conversion modifier in ToString(). So, this is two ways to get what you want.  If I had used Convert.ToByte, the second block would be redundant!

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Join("", from c in "12345" select ((int)c).ToString("X"));
```

Comment: snazzy... doesn't even look like C# anymore.

Comment: That is a very interesting statement.  I don't think the guys at my work would understand it (they were stuck in .NET 1.1 until about 6 months ago).

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "abc123";
foreach(char c in s)
{
   Response.Write((int)c + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it in a single line, and more readable (imo)

```
var result = "12345".Aggregate("", (res, c) => res + ((byte)c).ToString("X"));
```

this returns `"3132333435"`, just as you requested :)