# How to get ASCII value of characters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, character, ascii

Below is my string in `C#` which I am converting it to Character array & in need to get the ASCII value of each character in the string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Test";
        var arr = s.ToCharArray();
        foreach(var a in arr)
        {
            var n = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(a.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
```

This outputs as

```
T
1
e
1
s
1
t
1
```

On googling I got number of links but none of them suffice my need.

- [How to get ASCII value of string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400733/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-string-in-c-sharp)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/516802/ConvertingpluscharsplustoplusASCIIplusinplusC

I am in need to get the ASCII  value of each character in string.???

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002909/getting-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-in-a-c-sharp-string

Answer (score 3):

A `string` can be directly enumerated to a `IEnumerable<char>`. And each `char` can be casted to a integer to see its UNICODE "value" (code point). UTF-16 maps the 128 characters of ASCII (0-127) to the UNICODE code points 0-127 (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point), so you can directly print this number.

```
string s = "Test";
foreach (char a in s)
{
    if (a > 127)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format(@"{0} (code \u{1:X04}) is not ASCII!", a, (int)a));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", a, (int)a);
}
```

Comment: Yes.Correct Yours & Matt both ans suffice my need. I am upvoting your post but I have to accept one ans. Can you please check his post & add inputs which is better . I think your is better because it doesn;t involve an extra method calling What you say

Comment: I like the exception! But, you are putting a single UTF-16 code unit by itself into the message string, which might be valid in .NET but breaks some expectations. If you format it as `String.Format(@"\u{0:X04}…", (int)a)` then it would still be understood.

Answer (score 2):

Every character is represented in the ASCII table with a value between 0 and 127. Converting the chars to an Integer you will be able to get the ASCII value.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Test";
             for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Convert one by one every leter from the string in ASCII value.
                    int value = s[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

GetByteCount will return the count of bytes used, so for each character it will be 1 byte.

Try GetBytes

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Test";
        var n = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine($"Char {s[i]} - byte {n[i]}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.Correct Yours & xanatos both ans suffice my need. I am upvoting your post but I have to accept one ans. Can you please check his post & add inputs which is better

Comment: I think his suggestion is better because he doesn't involve a extra method.

Comment: Oh..Take care mate. & Please upvote my post if you find it worth? Thanks for sharing your inputs

Comment: Yes his may be more efficient.

Comment: This one will silently replace characters (codepoints) that are not in the ASCII character set with '?' (which is). You could still use this technique and get an exception instead if you prefer `Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII", EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback,  DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback).GetBytes("…")`.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the byte count when you should be asking for the bytes themselves. Use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` instead of `Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount`. Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/400777/3129333

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(a);   
Console.WriteLine(((int)a).ToString("X"));
```

You need to convert in int and then in hex.

`GetByteCount` will return the count of bytes used, so for each character it will be 1.

You can read also: [Need to convert string/char to ascii values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702978/need-to-convert-string-char-to-ascii-values)