# How to solve Check array index and length?

Tags: c#, byte, converters

Error message: **System.ArgumentException:** 'Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.'

```
public static string PassConv(string Password)
{
    int iLoop;
    int iL;
    int iTotal;
    int iValue;
    string sPassConv;

    iL = 3;
    iTotal = 0;

    for (iLoop = 1; iLoop <= Password.Length; iLoop++) {

        string sNo = Password.Substring(iLoop-1,1);

        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sNo);

        iValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(asciiBytes, 0); ---->**Error**

        iTotal = iTotal + iValue * (iL + iLoop - 1);  

        sPassConv = iTotal.ToString();

    }
    return sPassConv;
}
```

[image: What I wan to Do]
[image: From VB to C#]

Please Help
Thank

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do here? At the moment you're taking a single character from a string (`Password`), encoding that to bytes with ASCII encoding, and then trying to treat that byte data as a 4-byte binary value containing an integer. Since you're using ASCII, I'd expect that the length of `asciiBytes` will likely always be 1.

Comment: I'm assuming you really want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)?

Comment: Ah, you seem to want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370754/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-characters-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reach your idea because of so many redundancy codes. By using:

- `SubString` exports each character even `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` can return all byte array from these characters
- `BitConverter` expected of 4-byte binary input as well
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32 and seem this function is no help at all
- Declare iLoop = 1 but inside loop does iLoop - 1
- `sPassConv` gets value from iTotal so many times, should put outside the loop

Quick fix from your code:

```
public static string PassConv(string Password)
{
    int iLoop;
    int iL;
    int iTotal;
    int iValue;
    string sPassConv = "";

    iL = 3;
    iTotal = 0;

    for (iLoop = 1; iLoop <= Password.Length; iLoop++)
    {

        string sNo = Password.Substring(iLoop - 1, 1);

        iValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sNo)[0];

        iTotal = iTotal + iValue * (iL + iLoop - 1);

        sPassConv = iTotal.ToString();

    }
    return sPassConv;
}
```

A little bit refactor

```
public static string PassConv2(string Password, int iL = 3)
{
    int iTotal = 0;

    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password);

    for (var iLoop = 0; iLoop < bytes.Length; iLoop++)
    {
        // bytes[iLoop] = iValue
        iTotal += bytes[iLoop] * (iL + iLoop);
    }
    return iTotal.ToString();
}
```

This function is need to be improved because it does loop 2 times, first to bytes and second to calculate. Since every character can convert to `ASCII` even `Extended ASCII`, so we could cast it directly. `PassConv3` gives more exact when input is Unicode such as "Áaa", the `Encoding.ASCII.GetByteswill` cast as "?aa" with '?' represents 63 ASCII

```
public static string PassConv3(string Password, int iL = 3)
{
    int iTotal = 0;

    for (var iLoop = 0; iLoop < Password.Length; iLoop++)
    {
        iTotal += Password[iLoop] * (iL + iLoop);
    }
    return iTotal.ToString();
}
```

And the result

```
public static void MainFunc()
{
    Console.WriteLine(PassConv("ABCD")); // 1202
    Console.WriteLine(PassConv2("ABCD")); // 1202
    Console.WriteLine(PassConv3("ABCD")); // 1202
}
```

Hope it helps !